# Сыграть в( )сухую

Tags: слитно-раздельно

В ситуации, когда проигравшая сторона не заработала ни одного очка, какое из написаний следует считать более предпочтительным: "проиграла в сухую" или "проиграла всухую"?

Словарь С.И. Ожегова на моём столе предлагает только первый вариант; просмотренные мной он-лайн словари предлагают только второй. Кому в такой ситуации лучше доверять? Может, допустимы оба варианта написания?

Comment: А вас какого года словарь? У меня есть словарь Ожегова за 2006 г., но там этого слова нет.

Comment: В Национальном корпусе языке примеры показывают, что раздельное написание имеет свободное сочетание.

Comment: @Серж У меня 2003 г. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в конце статьи "Сухой".

Comment: Да, спасибо, нашел. Там, действительно, раздельное написание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следует выбрать слитное написание по ряду причин. Во-первых, большинство наречий  образованные от имен прилагательных и включающие в свой состав либо (а) полные формы, либо (б) краткие формы прилагательных (в том числе старые и теперь неупотребляемые), пишутся слитно,напр: **вживую, вкрутую, внаглую, впервые, вплотную, впрямую, врассыпную, врукопашную, вручную, втихую, вхолостую, вчистую**.

Во-вторых, как Вы отметили, онлайн словари предлагают слитное написание, в том числе Русский орфографический словарь РАН. Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

В-третьих, в толковом словаре Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992 также предлагается слитное написание.

Comment: Спасибо. Остаётся ещё посетовать на [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%D1%8E). В Розентале и в Лопатине не нашёл, но вот такие примеры встретил: в дым, в лоск, (пьяный) в стельку, в подбор, в придачу, в складчину, в старину, в стык, в тупик, в тупике; в головах, в ногах;

Comment: Я привёл примеры с существительными. Они сюда не подходят.

Comment: Вы знаете, в Викисловаре есть и слитное написание, они ссылаются на Тихонова там. К сожалению, ссылку не могу дать. В поисковике напишите "всухую" вам придет эта статья из Викисловоря.

Comment: Я видел эту статью, но она там числится в "непроверенных" и я счёл за менее надёжную. А ссылку на словарь не заметил. Спасибо!

Comment: В "Толковом словаре русского языка в 4-х т." мне удалось обнаружить статью: ***В сухую (или всухую) обыграть***. ◊    Как видите, такое написание встречается, но видимо, редко.

Comment: За это особое спасибо! Надо же как интересно.

Answer (score 3):

> *"проиграла в сухую"* или *"проиграла всухую"?*
>
> Словарь С.И. Ожегова на моём столе предлагает только первый вариант.

Видимо, Вы используете репринтное воспроизведение одного из первых изданий словаря Ожегова. В тех изданиях в словарной статье  **СУХОЙ** действительно имел место пример с использованием раздельного написания *"в сухую":*

> 9. *…Сыграть в сухую.*

См. снимок с 3-го издания словаря (1953 г.):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В последовавшие затем годы закрепилось слитное написание наречия *"всухую",* что нашло отражение и в орфографических словарях, и в новых изданиях  словаря Ожегова.

См. снимок с 16-го издания словаря Ожегова (1984 г.):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из словарной же статьи **СУХОЙ** пример с раздельным написанием *"в сухую"* был убран:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 24-е издание. М-да.. Кто бы мог подумать: "Воспроизводит последнее прижизненное издание". Об этом же нужно на титульных страницах предупреждать, а не в биографии автора :(

Comment: У меня 25-е издание, и там такое написание. Несмотря на то, что издание исправлено и дополнено. Ред. проф. Скворцов. Видимо, не заметили этого слова.